# How do you handle backward navigation in deeply nested route in Compose. For instance, from a Home route with bottom navigation back to auth route

Tags: android, nested, android-jetpack-compose, navcontroller, navhostcontroller

I am having a nested navigation. Since the Home route contains MainScreen with bottom navigation bar, it has it's own navhost and a navcontroller. Navigating forward is achievable but moving out of the MainScreen back to Auth route crashes the app.

The App crashes since it doesn't recognize the Root navhost when let's say one of the MainScreen's bottom navigation item is signOut.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.